# how to set image for anchor tag in mvc through css?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have the following cshtml and its working fine:

```
var calcButtonStyle = "font-size:smaller;font-weight:normal;position:absolute; width: " + string.Concat(@control.Width / 5, "px") + ";height:" + string.Concat(@control.Height / 5, "px") + ";left:" + string.Concat(@control.LeftLocation + @control.Width + 10, "px") + ";top:" + string.Concat(@control.TopLocation, "px") + " ";
<a href="#" onclick="CalculateExpression('@control.OptionList', '@control.FieldName')" style="@calcButtonStyle"><img src="~/Content/Images/_Summation.svg" /></a>
```

Now, what I want is separate the style(height,width and specially Image) to be rendered from CSS and the remaining as is.For that this is my css:

```
#test-compute {
  font-size:smaller;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: url('Images/_Summation.svg');
}
```

And in the cshtml, I am writing like:

```
var calcButtonStyle = "left:" + string.Concat(@control.LeftLocation + @control.Width + 10, "px") + ";top:" + string.Concat(@control.TopLocation, "px") + " ";
<a href="#" onclick="CalculateExpression('@control.OptionList', '@control.FieldName')" style="@calcButtonStyle" class="test-compute"></a>
```

But the image is not rendering, any idea where am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While not an answer to your question, I would advise pulling the CSS out of `var calcButtonStyle` and into a proper CSS sheet if viable, far easier to keep track of.

Comment: thats fine, but why the image is not rendering,thats my main issue!Thanks for your suggestion though!

Comment: Try adding a `display:block;` style to `#test-compute` and updating the path of the `background` to an absolute path like you have on your original `img` tag. i.e. `background: url('~/Content/Images/_Summation.svg');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the DOM element incorrectly, you are accessing by id with `#test-compute` which should be `.test-compute` to access by class.

Comment: Perfect!Just needed to make . instead of # for the css.

Comment: @AvishekRoyChowdhury well if it was because your css was targeting an id (`#`) instead of a class (`.`) then this answer is not the solution.

Comment: Also you can use single quotes this answer is just wrong. The quotes just have to match. either both ` or both ". See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vy4xydsz/)

Comment: Yup. Bad answer. Please un-accept so I can delete it. (I will edit it for now, but that's cheating really).

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling as long its the edited answer is the correct it should be fine so it can help people in the future. there is no cheating lol

Comment: Finally I am using this:  .test-compute {
  font-size:smaller;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-image: url(Images/summation.svg);
}  Is this right or wrong?(without any quotes)..its working for me, but still wanna know if this is the best practice?